# Select distinct values using like

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

not sure if the title really makes the question clear but basically I am using "SELECT DISTINCT" in a combobox to look at distinct log times , however the format of the log tim column (which cannot be changed) is  example :
           AUGUST 29th 9:21pm
           AUGUST 29th 9:22pm

This is no good as even using distinct will judge these as distinct because they are.
WHAT I WANT : I want an sql statement which will look at the values and select a distinct value based on just the first part e.g AUGUST 29th and not take the time into account.

Anyone got any ideas/code ?

UPDATE ::
I used ypercube's code and it works however   for the filter I want it so that when I select a date eg 29/08/2013 it then brings the datagrid cursor to the cell where the logtime matches this date , however the logtime must stay in the format "August 29th 9:21pm" , and ideas how to do this in c# ?

Comment: With "format" you mean that you are storing dates in `CHAR` columns?

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server? 2012, 2008R2, 2008, 2005? (you can use `SELECT @@VERSION ;` to check)

Comment: @ypercube the dates are varchar , using sql server 2012

Comment: And the format is as you show? Without a year? Only month, day, hours and minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is stored on a `DATETIME` column and you are one a recent version of SQL-Server, you can cast to `DATE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CAST(created_at AS DATE) AS date_created_at 
FROM
    SSISLog ;
```

Comment: that works great , thanks ! but for the filter I want it so that when I select a date eg 29/08/2013 it then brings the datagrid cursor to the cell where the logtime matches this date , however the logtime must stay in the format "August 29th 9:21pm" , and ideas how to do this in c# ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like following

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(created_at)) FROM users;
```

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server has `DATE()` as a function?

Comment: @Salil using your code I type execute query and the code gets changed to this :  SELECT DISTINCT DATE(created_at) AS Expr1
FROM SSISLog and I get an error saying DATE is not a recognised function type

Comment: Ref this you may get idea http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-date-functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(d, 0, cast(YourDateColumn as datetime)), 0) 
FROM LogTable
```

That would be pretty inefficient on a large dataset due to the cast. But since you can't change the table..otherwise I would have suggested adding a `persisted computed` column which does the cast on update to the table, and which you could have added an index.